# Docker Centos, Cannot Execute Binary File

Tags: c++, docker, centos, raspberry-pi3

I have one `C++ binary` which is running smoothly on local `centos`. Recently, I started learning `docker` and trying to run my `C++` application on `centos docker`.

Firstly, I pulled `centos:latest` from docker hub and installed my `C++` application on it and it ran successfully, without any issue. Now i installed docker on raspberry-pi and pulled centos again and tried to ran the same application on it but it gave me error.

> bash : cannot execute binary file

Usually, this error comes when we try to run application on different architecture then the one they are built on. I checked `cat etc/centos-release` on raspberry-pi and result is `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (AltArch)`,where as result on local centos is `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

`uname -a` on both devices is as follows

raspberry-pi, centos docker `Linux c475f349e7c2 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

centos, centos docker `Linux a57f3fc2c1a6 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

EDIT:
Also, `file myapplication`

`TTCHAIN: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=287b501c8206893f7819f215ee0033586212b143, with debug_info, not stripped`

My question is how can i ran the same native application of centos, pulled from docker on raspberry-pi model 3.

Answer (score 2):

Your application has been built for x86-64. Intel x86-64 binaries CAN NOT run on an ARM processor.

You have two paths to pursue:

1. If you don't have source code for the application, you will need an x86-64 emulator that will run on your Raspberry Pi. Considering the Pi's lesser capabilities and Intel's proclivity to sue anyone who creates an emulator for their processors, I doubt you'll find one that's publicly available.
2. If you have the source code for the application, you need to rebuild it as a Raspberry Pi executable. You seem to know that it was written in C++. GCC and other toolchains are available for the Raspberry Pi (most likely a "yum install gcc" on your Pi will grab the compiler and tools for you). Building the application should be extremely similar to building it for x86_64.

You *could* find a cross-compiler that would let you build for the Pi from your x86_64 box, but that can get complicated.

Comment: I did build the application for raspberryi-pi, but application is too big to be processed on raspberry-pi, that's why i was going for docker, to use it as a process, but looks like that's not a good path.

Comment: You may find this interesting... https://hackaday.com/2016/09/01/how-to-use-docker-to-cross-compile-for-raspberry-pi-and-more/ GIYF (Google is your friend) for this... I prefer DuckDuckGo, but you understand. There are many posts regarding how to set up a cross compile.

Comment: Even better... https://techsparx.com/software-development/docker-arm-cross-compile.html

Comment: i did cross compiling and on development on raspberry-pi too but when my application starts, it needs almost 3G of memory but raspberry-pi has only 1G available, So i get segmentation fault always> i tried this with cross-compilation also and with on raspberry-pi compilation also. I doubt it will even work with docker, but i thought it can be a good way for me to learn docker. Thanks

Comment: Also, i tried `swap` but still my application crashed on startup.

Comment: Also, i don't need docker to setup the cross compilation setup, i can only use the available toolchains to cross-compile and i did cross compilation by that way, but i just wanted to know and learn the docker.

Comment: My point of wondering about docker is that, docket is kind of VM, so it doesn't has to matter what OS is running inside the container, why it is running 'armv7 centos', why not x86_64 image/container?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are trying to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit processor, would need more information to know for sure though.

You can check by using the `file` command in the shell. You may have to re-compile on the original system with the `-m32` flag to gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Please do a "uname -a" on both devices and post the results.

Most likely the processor or library type doesn't match.

I presume (hope) you're not trying to run an x86-compiled app on a Pi. Although Docker is available for both processor types, Docker will not run x86 binaries on Pi or vice versa.

Actually, AltArch currently means one of the following architectures... ppc64, ppc64le, i386, armhfp (arm v7 32-bit), aarch64 (arm v8 64-bit). Core suggests the mainstream x86 and x86_64 builds of CentOS.

Yep, I bet that's what it is...you can't just transfer an x86 binary to a Raspbian and expect it to work. The application must be rebuilt for the platform.